# Best way to write a String to OutputStream in Java

Tags: java, text, utf-8, io, outputstream

I have an `OutputStream` instance which return from `HttpURLConnection`. I need to write a UTF-8 String into the stream.

I have 2 ways:

1. Use `OutputStream` itself

   ```
   // write String
   os.write("some utf8 text".getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8));
   ```
2. Use `OutputStreamWriter` wrapper

   ```
   // BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, CharsetUtils.UTF_8));

   OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, CharsetUtils.UTF_8);
   osw.write("some utf8 text");
   ```

**Question**: Why should we use `OutputStreamWriter` over `OutputStream` to write String?

Thanks!

Comment: Because most of the time, you want to write many Strings (and possibly other data types, using a PrintWriter wrapping the OuputStreamWriter) to the same stream, and don't want to repeat the encoding every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Question: Why should we use OutputStreamWriter over OutputStream to
>   write String?

Simply to define the encoding **only once** in the constructor of `OutputStreamWriter` instead of specifying each time we want to encode a `String` into `UTF-8` thanks to `getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8)`

Moreover an `OutputStreamWriter` provides many convenient methods to write `String` such as `write(String)`, `write(String, int, int)`, `append(CharSequence)` and `append(CharSequence, int, int)` that you don't have in an `OutputStream`.

Comment: Thank you. It is one reason. But for performance, are they the same?

Comment: you should alway think about maintainability before performances, anyway I never checked but I would not worry about that If I were you just trust Sun/Oracle engineers :-)

Comment: OutputStreamWriter is meant to be used for this purpose so I believe that it should be optimized enough